# Finde android keystore file

Tags: android, macos, unix, keystore, android-keystore

I have an android app I developed years ago.
I can't find the Keystore I used for signing the app.

It's somewhere on my computer (macOS).

Is there any way to search through all files on the computer and detect all Keystore files by their content or any other way??

Answer (score 0):

macOS provides a built-in tool named **keychain Access**(located in Applications/Utilities)

1 Click the item(I create a test keystore)

[image]

2 Tick the checkbox, then input your **mac user password**
[image]
[image]

3 Then get the keystore password
[image]

Comment: Thanks but this only show things installed/used by the os. not some Keystore file sitting someplace on the computer.

if I use android studio to generate a new Keystore and save it on the desktop, it will not show

Comment: In fact my test keystore is generated by using android studio. Maybe you could try Build--Generate Signed Bundle or APK